# Hello... eh, who?

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-source, hello-world

## Introduction

You started to write a "Hello, World!" program, but after you wrote the part to print the hello, you forgot what your program should actually print. So now, you somehow managed it to write a program which can check if the entered word is what you search.

## The task

Your task is to write a program or function, which first prints `Hello... eh, whom should I greet?`, then asks for input, and if the input equals `world` ignoring capitalization, the program should print `Ah, yes. World.`, else it should print `No. That isn't what I meant.`.

**But** you are not allowed to use any of the bytes equivalent to the ASCII values of:
`worldWORLD`
- that is, for those using code-pages not aligned with ASCII, bytes:
`0x...:` `77, 6f, 72, 6c, 64, 57, 4f, 52, 4c, 44`.

## Compact rules

- No substring of the byte-string `worldWORLD` may appear in your program or in the file name of the program on any way
- `print "Hello... eh, whom should I greet?"; if input.lower == "world" print "Ah, yes. World."; else print "No. That isn't what I meant.";`
- Leading or trailing spaces are ignored.
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the program with the lowest amount of chars wins!

Comment: "But you are not allowed to use any of the chars w, o, r, l or d in any capitalization in your program." - what if my language doesn't use any of these characters? Or rather, what if it uses raw bytes rather than characters?

Comment: @JanDvorak Well, then you're lucky. The chars are needed in the string "world", which appears at least one time, but if you found a way to ignore that, you solved the question :D

Comment: I've downvoted this challenge, because I don't think it's very easily golfable. There's not really more than 1 way to do this, which is `print string; input(); isequal? string1 : string2`.  It panders to golfing languages with those builtins not assigned to `world` and with short names.

Comment: @CartManagerXD [Here](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#U9Z71DfV0/9R2wSD/2lAsjoZRADFHMOiD603MtUGMx/1bn7UuzW2lgvIA8onqx9u1DM1tXB3d8/VMzy0JfdRR5uhhVnuoaWGFocWmx5an3u4KdfgUdciPT2VR72T1LmAGrot3HMPTzKsUsk1OrTUvEwFrAfIA6o006syV3FXV1CPMsx10ju0FKhwqgVQN9Agd/VHXc2PeldoJKsD1UMF1TUfdS60MLR81LPtUe@82v//0xQe9a7hSspJzOCCMMPzg3JcAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – TIO Nexus") is a functional equivalent of [my below program submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117400/43319), although it breaks FP best practices of avoiding sideeffects and non-argument data.

Comment: I've upvoted this challenge, as there is in fact a lot of ways to golf it. See Python 3 submissions in [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187816/swapping-good-and-bad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 67 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
P5√~!9!j┌⁰‚V{7Χ←½χķ²‘q"A6‘,u=?"ΤΞ¦▲ξ⌠²ō⅞Σ↔─╚‘p}"⁽∙šžøp⅔…ļ4∑Ν…ZH]└»‘
```

Explanation:

```
...‘                        push "Hello... eh, whom should I greet?"
    q                       output, without disabling implicit output
     "A6‘                   push "world"
         ,u=?       }       if equal to lowercased input
             "....‘           push "Ah, yes. World."
                   p          output, disabling implicit output
                     "...‘  push "No. That isn't what I meant."
                            implicitly output that if that hasn't been disabled by the if.
```

Comment: FYI - I know you answered before the hold, but I made an edit to make the challenge a little more language-agnostic. If that holds this would no longer be valid (it contains one `P` and two `p`s, `0x4f` and `0x6f` respectively, I believe).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh. Never noticed that the byte table of SOGL is not ASCII-aligned, trough it's supposed to be. The problem with fixing that is that (almost) all my previous answers would not work with that being fixed.

Comment: Oh, I thought it might have been on purpose. You could change your / make a second code page - languages can change, although I agree it could confuse. I am surprised, once again, by how short the compressions are. Would you mind adding an answer to the [tips question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/117387/53748) I just asked?!

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 70 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
“¡Kịy<⁷ẊṘṘsṁñAỵḋẇ,ẇʂI»Ṅø“¢ƈṫ(Ɲ¬÷Ø“¡ṣƓ»µɠŒteḊȧKȯ“TḲj/Ẇi¤cecṡĿt⁺ƘNƁ⁻»;”.
```

Jelly's code-page is equal to ASCII in the range `' '`, `0x20`, through to `'~'`, `0x7e`, inclusive so the lack of any of `worldWORLD` in the code above suffices (note: `ẇȯṘĿḊ` are not `woRLD` or equivalent bytes.)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYc6hhd4Pd3dX2jxq3P5wV9fDnTOAqPjhzsbDGx0f7t76cEf3w13tOkB8qsnz0O6HO1sO7wBpWnSs4@HO1RrH5h5ac3j74RkgoaUPd7Q83DHv0O5DQF1dbkD8qHHPyQVHJ5UcWnJi@Yn1QDUhD3dsytJ/uKst89CS5NTkhzsXHtlf8qhx17EZfscaHzXuPrTb@lHDXL3//8v9i3xSAA)**

This took a little fiddling to avoid the forbidden bytes:
all the naive string compressions contained illegal characters;
finding the first index of a sublist within another is performed with the `w` atom;
finding the length of a list (for chopping and measuring to replace `w`) uses `L` - something I considered was summing the indices with `JS` (triangle(9)=45), I ended up using a list of strings and a separate trailing period to kill three birds with one stone <sup>[sic]</sup>, allowing a dequeue-flatten-dequeue chain, `ḊFḊ`, to pick out the word `World`, this can be further shortened by post-joining the list with the space using `Ḳ`, allowing for a simple dequeue, `Ḋ` to be used instead saving another byte.

Adding the trailing period to whichever response is output as a single action also allowed compression without illegal bytes.

For some reason, the word `yes` is not in Jelly's dictionary, yet even though compressing `Ah, yes.` is the same length as the raw string, having the compression as a list of strings `['Ah, yes.',' World']` (`“¢ƈṫ(Ɲ¬÷Ø“¥ḄḞ»`) is shorter by two bytes than concatenating (`“Ah, yes.”;“¥ḄḞ»`), the *third bird*.

For the first message I compressed `Hell` as a word and prepended the string '...' with an 'o' to avoid the forbidden bytes.

Commented code:

```
W: “¡Kịy<⁷ẊṘṘsṁñAỵḋẇ,ẇʂI» - compressed string "Hello... eh, whom should I greet?"

R: “¢ƈṫ(Ɲ¬÷Ø“¡ṣƓ» - compressed list of strings ["Ah, yes.","World"]

D: “TḲj/Ẇi¤cecṡĿt⁺ƘNƁ⁻» - compressed string "No. That isn't what I meant"

WṄøRµɠŒteḊȧKȯD;”. - Main link: no arguments
W                 - "Hello... eh, whom should I greet?"
 Ṅ                - print and yield
  ø               - niladic chain separation, no input to the following
   R              - ["Ah, yes.","World"]
    µ             - monadic chain separation, call that L
     ɠ            - read a line from STDIN
      Œt          - title-case it (e.g. "wOrLd" -> "World")
         Ḋ        - dequeue L: ["World"]
        e         - exists in?       (0 or 1)
          ȧ       - and L            (0 or ["Ah, yes.","World"])
           K      - join with spaces (0 or "Ah, yes. World")
             D    - "No. That isn't what I meant"
            ȯ     - or               ("No. That isn't what I meant" or "Ah, yes. World")
               ”. - literal '.'
              ;   - concatenate      ("No. That isn't what I meant." or "Ah, yes. World.")
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>376</s> 361 bytes

```java
v->{System.\u006Fut.p\u0072int\u006Cn("He\u006C\u006C\u006F... eh, \u0077h\u006Fm sh\u006Fu\u006C\u0064 I g\u0072eet?");System.\u006Fut.p\u0072int\u006Cn(ne\u0077 java.uti\u006C.Scanne\u0072(System.in).next().equa\u006CsIgn\u006F\u0072eCase("\u0077\u006F\u0072\u006C\u0064")?"Ah, yes. \u0057\u006F\u0072\u006C\u0064.":"N\u006F. That isn't \u0077hat I meant.");}
```

-15 bytes switching from Java 7 to 8.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hVFNSwMxEL33Vwy5mAU7lKIWLFqkUtyDPVjRg3qI27HNujutTbJYSn/7mt1E2It4mcwXb/Ley1Wl@vnys84KZQzcK82HHoBmS7sPlRHMmxKg2uglZPKpeapk7HvHng/GKqszmAPDVV31rw@LvbFU4qsbDC5mzuK2yUZDj9e2pizFHYW0E2eICLQ@hXZ7tA7NEkzMXGf3DFJYBVQiOxHJ@P@bTAEYck8XndVhgItMcZwNZYTRnCDTt5UJ0pdTYdOkKw748fJUGZIioHYH3Y@KZCJuPKk9GWyZnf@5iuJSzKMU8LhWFrThE/urh69TKEmxRc/3WDf6b9174aWPDrT@lN49ubA7zauXN5UE5xgzya4oomnH@nnzUNz@AA)

**Explanation:**

In Java you can use unicode escapes in the form of `\u####`. Fortunately, `u` wasn't one of the disallowed characters, so I've used these unicode escapes for the characters that are disallowed.

The method above, without unicode escapes:

```java
v->{                            // Method with empty unused parameter & no return
  System.out.println("Hello... eh, whom should I greet?");
                                //  Print the greetings line
  System.out.println(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).next()
                                //  Get the user input from STDIN
    .equalsIgnoreCase("world")? //  If it's equal to (case-insensitive) "world":
      "Ah, yes. World."         //   Print the World-response line
    :                           //  Else:
      "No. That isn't what I meant.");}
                                //   Print the No-response line
```

Taking the input as parameter and returning a String instead of using STDIN/STDOUT (which I think is allowed reading the challenge again, so not sure why I hadn't done that four years ago when I posted my answer), it would be **239 bytes** instead:

```java
s->"He\u006C\u006C\u006F... eh, \u0077h\u006Fm sh\u006Fu\u006C\u0064 I g\u0072eet?\n"+(s.equa\u006CsIgn\u006F\u0072eCase("\u0077\u006F\u0072\u006C\u0064")?"Ah, yes. \u0057\u006F\u0072\u006C\u0064.":"N\u006F. That isn't \u0077hat I meant.")
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dZBBS8NAEIXv/RXDXtxFuxRRC4oWqYg5mIMKHqyHMR2TrcmmdiaFIv3tcdOskIuXYd7M29nHt8ItjlfLrzYrkRke0fmfEYDzQptPzAjSTgI8y8b5HDIdGzZXYb4fhcKC4jJIwcN1y@Mb9UCLZjK5mA/qvbUWqDiBTk2nRT@sgGPXDLxnkEB@8J0SyWzh1bFmS98N9iZOct@/iqY5MmnVXx4uhjeVmanb8P@O2B5CnP9rtepSpTE1vBQo4NgfyV/0oBOoCL1YZdqOwrr5KAOAyGFbuyVUgWNE9faOJjLcsVBl60bsOmyk9NrbTKvX@qm8UyYS3be/)

Comment: You could use Java 8 and turn it into a lambda by replacing `v\u006Fi\u0064 c()` with `()->`.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>484</s> 347 bytes

This is horrible and could most likely be golfed more. Just seeing if I could answer in JavaScript with the restrictions.

```
z=({}+[]+{})[-~[]]
y=(!![]+[])[+!+[]]
x=([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]
v=this
c=n=>v[`St${y}ing`][`f${y}${z}mCha${y}C${z}${x}e`](n*9)
u=c(12)
t=c(13.3)
v[s=`a${u}e${y}t`](`He${u+u+z}... eh, ${t}h${z}m sh${z}u${u+x} I g${y}eet?`)
v[s](v[`p${y+z}mpt`]()[`t${z+c(8.5)+z+t}e${y+c(7.5)}ase`]()==t+(s=z+y+u+x)?`Ah, yes. ${c(9.7)+s}.`:`N${z}. That isn't ${t}hat I meant.`)
```

#### Try it online!

```js
z=({}+[]+{})[-~[]]
y=(!![]+[])[+!+[]]
x=([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]
v=this
c=n=>v[`St${y}ing`][`f${y}${z}mCha${y}C${z}${x}e`](n*9)
u=c(12)
t=c(13.3)
v[s=`a${u}e${y}t`](`He${u+u+z}... eh, ${t}h${z}m sh${z}u${u+x} I g${y}eet?`)
v[s](v[`p${y+z}mpt`]()[`t${z+c(8.5)+z+t}e${y+c(7.5)}ase`]()==t+(s=z+y+u+x)?`Ah, yes. ${c(9.7)+s}.`:`N${z}. That isn't ${t}hat I meant.`)
```

Comment: z,y and x are JSF*ck, right?

Comment: @MegaMan sort of but not quite. `-~{}` are not in the allowed characters.

Comment: Oh. Of course :P But x and y are.

Comment: @MegaMan definitely.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>215</s> 247 bytes

If I've understood correctly, the challenge is to not use any of the following chracters: `0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, c, d, f, l, o, r, w, x, D, L, O, R, W`.

```
(t=this,T=""+t,A=T[8],a=T[13],b=T[1],e=(""+!!1)[1],g=(""+!1)[3-1],h=T[11])=>t[`p${e+b}mpt`](`He${g+g+b}... eh, ${a}h${b}m sh${b}u${g+h} I g${e}eet?`)[`t${b}L${b+a}e${e}Case`]()==a+(z=b+e+g+h)?`Ah, yes. ${A+z}.`:`N${b}. That isn't ${a}hat I meant.`
```

---

### Try It

```js
y=
(t=this,T=""+t,A=T[8],a=T[13],b=T[1],e=(""+!!1)[1],g=(""+!1)[3-1],h=T[11])=>t[`p${e+b}mpt`](`He${g+g+b}... eh, ${a}h${b}m sh${b}u${g+h} I g${e}eet?`)[`t${b}L${b+a}e${e}Case`]()==a+(z=b+e+g+h)?`Ah, yes. ${A+z}.`:`N${b}. That isn't ${a}hat I meant.`
alert(y())
```

### Explanation

```
t=this         // assigns the window object to variable t
T=""+t         // converts t to a string ("[object Window]") and assigns it to variable T
A=T[8]         // assigns the 9th character of T ("W") to variable A
a=T[13]        // assigns the 14th character of T ("w") to variable a
b=T[1]         // assigns the 2nd character of T ("o") to variable b
e=(""+!!1)[1]  // converts true to a string and assigns the 2nd character ("r") to variable e
g=(""+!1)[3-1] // converts false to a string and assigns the 3rd character ("l") to variable g
               // (1 is a truthy value in JS, so !1=false and !!1=true)
h=T[11]        // assigns the 12th character of T ("d") to variable h

// The rest then uses template literals and the above variables to construct the following:

window["prompt"]("Hello... eh, whom should I greet?")["toLowerCase"]()=="w"+(z="orld")?
"Ah, yes. W"+z:
"No. That isn't what I meant."
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 71 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.•ǝ·Þ•“Ÿ™...Ûß,£Ô‚© I ÿ?“ćuì,u‘‚ï‘Qi“ºÆ,…Ü.‚ï.“ë“€¸.€Š€ˆn't€À I±….“}.ª,
```

05AB1E uses a custom code-page, but the lower- and uppercase characters are on the same hexadecimal positions on the code-page, so as long as I don't use `worldWORLD` it's fine.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f71HDouNzD20/PA/IeNQw5@iORy2L9PT0Ds8@PF/n0OLDUx41zDq0UsFT4fB@e6D0kfbSw2t0Sh81zACKH14PpAMzgcKHdh1u03nUsOzwHD2wOJCcc3g1kHjUtObQDj0geXQBkDjdlqdeAqQPNyh4HtoIVA9SV6t3aJXO///l/kU@KQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
.•ǝ·Þ•               # Push compressed string "greet" (which unfortunately isn't part of
                     # the dictionary, AND contains an 'r'..)
 “Ÿ™...Ûß,£Ô‚© I ÿ?“ # Push dictionary string "hello... eh, whom should I ÿ?",
                     # where the `ÿ` is filled with the "greet" we pushed earlier
  ć                  # Extract head; pop and push remainder and first character separately
   u                 # Uppercase this first character
    ì                # Prepend it back to the remainder-string
     ,               # And output it to STDOUT with trailing newline
u                    # Convert the (implicit) input-string to uppercase
 ‘‚ï‘                # Push dictionary string "WORLD"
     Qi              # If they are equal:
       “ºÆ,…Ü.‚ï.“   #  Push dictionary string "ah, yes. world."
      ë              # Else:
       “€¸.€Š€ˆn't€À I±….“
                    '#  Push dictionary string "no. that isn't what I meant."
      }.ª            # After the if-else: sentence capitalize the string
         ,           # And also output it to STDOUT
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `.•ǝ·Þ•` is `"greet"`; `“Ÿ™...Ûß,£Ô‚© I ÿ?“` is `"hello... eh, whom should I ÿ?"`; `‘‚ï‘` is `"WORLD"`; `“ºÆ,…Ü.‚ï.“` is `"ah, yes. world."`; and `“€¸.€Š€ˆn't€À I±….“` is `"no. that isn't what I meant."`.

If all characters would be allowed, there are only two minor differences:

- The `greet` would have been placed literally inside the dictionary sentence
- The input would have been changed to lowercase with `l` instead, so `'‚ï` could be used for `"world"`

So it would be **68 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** instead:

```python
“Ÿ™...Ûß,£Ô‚© I greet?“ćuì,l'‚ïQi“ºÆ,…Ü.‚ï.“ë“€¸.€Š€ˆn't€À I±….“}.ª,
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOcozsetSzS09M7PPvwfJ1Diw9PedQw69BKBU@F9KLU1BJ7oIoj7aWH1@jkqAMlDq8PzASKHNp1uE3nUcOyw3P0wIJAcs7h1UDiUdOaQzv0gOTRBUDidFueegmQPtyg4HloI1A9SF2t3qFVOv//l/sX@aQAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 75 bytes

```
`ƈṡ... eh, ↓Ṅ ƛ¤ I £Ẋet?`,⇩`ƛ†`=[`Ah, ∨ȯ. ƛ€.`,|«ƛτ«ǐ`. λ÷ ⋏°'t λ⟨ I ḋ↓.`J,
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgxojhuaEuLi4gZWgsIOKGk+G5hCDGm8KkIEkgwqPhuopldD9gLOKHqWDGm+KAoGA9W2BBaCwg4oioyK8uIMab4oKsLmAsfMKrxpvPhMKrx5BgLiDOu8O3IOKLj8KwJ3Qgzrvin6ggSSDhuIvihpMuYEosIiwiIiwiV29SbEQiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 171 bytes

No compression here!

Requires `⎕IO←0` which is default on many systems. All characters are in [the character set](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319).

```apl
c←{⎕AV[¯25+⎕AV⍳⍵]}
c'Á.558GGGm.1´m∆186m¥18£5¯mÂm0⊢..$⍒'
c'Ë8GmÒ1z$m2¥7v$m∆1z$mÂm6.z7$G' 'Z1mB.¥GmÕ8⊢5¯G'⊃⍨(c'∆8⊢5¯')≡819⌶⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#U9Z71DfV0/9R2wQDrkcd7Wn/k4HMaqCYY1j0ofVGptpg5qPezY96t8bWciWrH27UMzW1cHd3z9UzPLQl91FHm6GFWe6hpYYWhxabHlqfe7gp1@BR1yI9PZVHvZPUQRq6LdxzD08yrFLJNTq01LxMBawHyAOqNNOrMldxV1dQjzLMddI7tBSocKoFUDfQIHf1R13Nj3pXaCSrA9VDBdU1H3UutDC0fNSz7VHvvP9AB/9P40rKSczgSuMKzw/KcQEA)

Works by first defining a custom decoding function `c` which decodes from a simple shifted encoding which was carefully chosen to be able to represent all the required strings while avoiding the ten forbidden characters.

`c←{`…`}` a function:
 `⎕AV[`…`]` the **A**tomic **V**ector indexed by
  `¯25+` the downshifted-by-25
  `⎕AV⍳` indices into the **A**tomic **V**ector for
  `⍵` the argument

`c'Á.558GGGm.1´m∆186m¥18£5¯mÂm0⊢..$⍒'` implicitly print the decoded *Hello... eh, whom should I greet?*

`⍞` get character input
`819⌶` lowercase it
`(`…`)≡` compare it to
 `c'∆8⊢5¯'`  the decoded *world*
`'Ë8GmÒ1z$m2¥7v$m∆1z$mÂm6.z7$G' 'Z1mB.¥GmÕ8⊢5¯G'⊃⍨` use that Boolean to pick from the encoded *No. That isn't what I meant.* (if false) and *Ah yes. World.* (if true)
`c` decode that

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 186 bytes

```python
t=a,b,c,e,f=5*'%c'%(87,111,114,108,100)
exec(f'exit(["N{b}. That isn\'t \u0077hat I meant.","Ah, yes. {t}."][input("He{e+e+b}... eh, \u0077h{b}m sh{b}u{e+f} I g{c}eet?").tit{e}e()==t])')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBRa8IwEMff8ymOgEtTQ2nZhuIoY7CHCeJgDPagMmJ6XQOaShqnEvLZu1R82MNx3PG/393/DhfXtOa@V22FUIKllPaulGIrlEBRl48pGyk2SqYTURRFjAdR5NMYOSd4RpXUDM/aJSu69NuQwWcjHejOrJmD9THPJ5OhMYc9SuMyKuhLI@CCXQbehYxuVtocji6hb@hxjOOIyDLAqLkNR@geuiEdo6AOEfXjVUB0z5RnTjuPARNelm7DGe/j@YRo49B2qJxuTfTk08FcuPMpO7V2V329fyxeWYDWgl@2BgM52DiSsLn5lTtdgWqklWpgzJiA9D@O37SckMF2ea1IHVHfoA3kopjB9S3DSv4EN3V/ereLiux3srr8AQ)

Outputs to `STDERR`.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>76</s> 73 bytes

```
u”Ÿ™... ”“Ûß,£Ô‚© I g“«’‚™ˆÆ?’«,‘‚ï‘Qi“ºÆ,…Ü.‚ï.“ë“€¸.€Š€ˆn't€À I±….“}.ª,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/9FHD3KM7HrUs0tPTUwCyHzXMOTz78HydQ4sPT3nUMOvQSgVPhXSg4KHVjxpmAgWAKk@3HW6zB/IOrdZ51DADKHZ4PZAOzASp2nW4DSi47PAcPbC4Hsg4oM45j5rWHNqhBySPLgASp9vy1EuA9OEGBc9DG4HqQepq9Q6t0vn/HwA)

*-3 bytes thanks to [@ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).*

```
                                # (implicit) push STDIN to stack
u                               # convert top of stack to uppercase
”Ÿ™... ”“Ûß,£Ô‚© I g“«’‚™ˆÆ?’«  # push "Hello... eh, whom do I greet?"
,                               # output top of stack to STDOUT
‘‚ï‘                            # push "WORLD"
  Qi                            # if top two stack values are equal...
    “ºÆ,…Ü.‚ï.“                 # push "ah, yes. world."
  ë                             # else... 
    “€¸.€Š€ˆn't€À I±….“         # push "no. that isn't what I meant."
}                               # exit if statement
.ª                              # push top of stack in sentence case
,                               # output top of stack to STDOUT
```

Comment: Nice answer! If you use `ë`lse, you can save some bytes on the repeated `.ª`: https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/51HD3KM7HrUs0tPTUwCyHzXMOTz78HydQ4sPT3nUMOvQSgVPhXSg4KHVjxpmAgWAKk@3HW6zB/IOrdYBSgDFDq8H0oGZIFW7DrcBBZcdnqMHFtcDGbcapKppzaEdekDy6AIgcbotT70ESB9uUPA8tBGoHqSuVu/QKp3//wE

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 1445 bytes

```
->-[------->+<]>-.-[->+++++<]>++.+++++++..+++.[->+++++<]>+++...++[--->++<]>.+[->+++<]>++.+++.----[->+++<]>.------------.--[->++++<]>-.+[->+++<]>.+++++++.--.[->+++++<]>-.---[->++++<]>-.-----------.+++++++.++++++.---------.--------.-[--->+<]>-.++++[->++<]>+.-[->++++<]>.++[->+++<]>+.+++++++++++.-------------..[--->+<]>---.-[->+++++<]>.[-]+[-<+]->>>,[>>+<+<-]<------[>+++<--]>[->-<]+>[<->[-]]<[<<+>>-]-[>+<---]>++[->-<]+>[<->[-]]<[<<<+>>>-]+[-<+]->>>,[>>+<+<-]<-[>--<-------]>+[->-<]+>[<->[-]]<[<<+>>-]-[>+<---]>------[->-<]+>[<->[-]]<[<<<+>>>-]+[-<+]->>>,[>>+<+<-]<-[>++<+++++++++]>[->-<]+>[<->[-]]<[<<+>>-]-[>+<---]>---[->-<]+>[<->[-]]<[<<<+>>>-]+[-<+]->>>,[>>+<+<-]<-[>--<-------]>--[->-<]+>[<->[-]]<[<<+>>-]-[>+<-------]>+++[->-<]+>[<->[-]]<[<<<+>>>-]+[-<+]->>>,[>>+<+<-]<-[>++<-----]>--[->-<]+>[<->[-]]<[<<+>>-]----[>---<----]>+[->-<]+>[<->[-]]<[<<<+>>>-]+[-<+]->>,[<+>-]<-----[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]+>[>-[--->+<]>-------.-[--->+<]>.[->+++++<]>+++.++[--->++<]>.>-[--->+<]>-.[---->+++++<]>-.-------.--[--->+<]>-.[---->+<]>+++.-[--->++<]>-.++++++++++.-----.[++>---<]>++.[->+++<]>-.[---->+<]>+++.--[->++++<]>-.+[->+++<]>.-------.--[--->+<]>-.[---->+<]>+++.++++[->++<]>+.-[->++++<]>.+[----->+<]>.--------.----.+++++++++++++.++++++.[++>---<]>.+[-<+]->>->[-]]<[>>----[---->+<]>++.[--->+<]>---.----[->+++<]>.------------.--[->++++<]>+.--[->+++<]>.[--->+<]>----.+[++>---<]>.++[--->++<]>.---[->+++<]>.-[--->+<]>---.+++.------.--------.[->+++<]>++.+[-<+]->>-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVRbbgMxCDwQgRNYXAT5ow9Vqhq1UqQox9@CX2A3G23jr13MzBjM@PXy8vn9cX372jZkFKyLIWVG0n8GW/oHQFAX2QdNWxrToBSkRQjq9sCRsY4YYVjUN6qmI4ee5gQ1A0yIyNUhA@ki/UO8PsuRdmSgQEoQCuikM2MhIyfDuV26k5UjQUZmPglrFiTMqSKlkCNmVgymDCwJ9TvnJCkBM2bLsWxr4b0ky@I9EdEDNSkjOCDSzvV/Ia1jtOdQOc/JxHruE0wyrfCnWgeN4bFQuUVsx9rp8Sp0Eo30IVAhFU02AyWqUMY4UMu8rpabDBeRZSoXwwynrUmNDJ0LaZ13EoBSarHzcMYfjj0jH9B/YEXxJ4kmP0djuuf9rDT63m@EuQ65Ky8OPvZKean1WsKVqWbQjzc0U0@y/rB4gdMDOurI23b7uZzffwE)

Requires an 8-bit wrapping implementation where EOF=0.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>211</s> 194 bytes

```
T`a-z`A-Z
T`A-Z`A-C\E-KMNPQS-VX-Z(%[]{
^(?!%SVNE$).*
Qs. Yiay jxq'y =iay J pfaqy.
%SVNE
Ai, *fx. %svne.
^
Ifnns... fi, =isp xiszne J hvffy?¶
T`A-C\E-KMNPQS-VX-Z(%[]{a-ce-kmn\pqs-vx-z}=+*&`A-Za-z
```

Explanation:

```
T`a-z`A-Z - Stage one (uppercasing input)
T`     Configuration - Transliterate;
a-z    Lowercase letters of the alphabet
`      ...into...
A-Z    Uppercase letters of the alphabet

T`A-Z`A-C\E-KMNPQS-VX-Z(%[]{ - Stage two (encoding input)
T`                             Configuration - Transliterate:
A-Z                            Uppercase letters of the alphabet
`                              ...into...
A-C\E-KMNPQS-VX-Z              All uppercase characters, excluding "WORLD"
                 (%[]{         And these characters to make up for the missing 5 characters

^(?!%SVNE$).*
Qs. Yiay jxq'y =iay J pfaqy. - Stage three (check whether input is not "world")
                               Implicit Configuration - Replace:
^(?!%SVNE$).*                  Anything except "%SVNE" (the encoded version of "WORLD") with
Qs. Yiay jxq'y =iay J pfaqy.   This line (encoded version of "No. That isn't what I meant.").

%SVNE
Ai, *fx. %svne.    - Stage four (check whether input is "world")
                     Implicit Configuration - Replace:
%SVNE                %SVNE with
Ai, *fx. %svne.      This line (the encoded version of "Ah, yes. World.")

^
Ifnns... fi, =isp xiszne J hvffy?¶ - Stage five (append message to start)
                                     Implicit Configuration - Replace:
^                                    The start with
Ifnns... fi, =isp xiszne J hvffy?¶   This line (the encoded version of ("Hello... eh, whom should I greet?"). The ¶ represents a newline

T`A-C\E-KMNPQS-VX-Z(%[]{a-ce-kmn\pqs-vx-z}=+*&`A-Za-z - Stage six (decode)
T`                                                      Configuration - Transliterate:
A-C\E-KMNPQS-VX-Z                                       All uppercase characters, excluding "WORLD"
                 (%[]{                                  And these characters to make up for the missing 5 characters
A-C\E-KMNPQS-VX-Z                                       All lowercase characters, excluding "world"
                 }=+*&                                  And these characters to make up for the missing 5 characters
`                                                       ...with...
A-Za-z                                                  All the uppercase characters followed by the lowercase characters.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@x@SkKhbleCoG8UVAiKB2DnGVdfb1y8gMFg3LEI3SkM1OraaK07DXlE1OMzPVUVTT4srsFhPITIzsVIhq6JQvVLBFsT0UihISyys1OMCK@NyzNRR0Eqr0FNQLS7LS9XjiuPyTMvLK9bT01NIA0rZZhYXKFRkFlflpQJ1ZpSlpVXaH9oGdgM2@xN1k1N1s3PzYgoKi3XLKnSram21tdRADga6/v//8vyiHBcA)

I used [this](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@x@S4KgblahbBaScY1x1vX39AgKDdcMidKM0VKNjqxN1k1N1s3PzYgoKi3XLKnSram21tdT@/3fM0FGoTC3WUwjPL8pJ0QMA) program to encode the strings, and [this](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@x@S4KjrHOOq6@3rFxAYrBsWoRuloRodW52om5yqm52bF1NQWKxbVqFbVWurraUGVByVqFv1/79jpo6CVlqFnoJqcVleqh4A) one to decode them.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3.7, <s>239</s> <s>267</s> <s>260</s> 258 bytes

```python
a,b,c,e,f,g='\u0057','\u0077','\u006f','\u0072','\u006c','\u0064'
exec(f'p=p{e}int;p("He{f}{f}{c}... eh, {b}h{c}m sh{c}u{f}{g} I g{e}eet?");p("Ah, yes. {a}{c}{e}{f}{g}."if input().{f}{c}{b}e{e}()=="{b}{c}{e}{f}{g}"e{f}se"N{c}. That isn\'t {b}hat I meant.")')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY8/C8IwEMV3P8WRJQnIUfzXqYgIYhcnxy5FTpOhsZgr2E8faxMhi8tx93j3471@ZPN06xD6l3WsxJmaoSh2x2yeEBHILOF7laWJYgc@bUPm3UANj9m3IuK90At6003JRD9MlJE8zqhtGf@jPYegsHewrh9YacyTxAQUP5SuKhGVfyCR2ngSl9QFrqZlsN41kn@NJqGGjlrHKLTUIXwA)

I had to write `exec` because I had to write `p\u0072int` instead of `print`, `e\u006Cse` instead of `else` and `\u006C\u006F\u0077e\u0072` instead of `lower`.

Comment: Your code isn't case insensitive.

Comment: @G.Sliepen oh i misunderstood the question then lol, ill edit it

Comment: Your code contains the letter `r` in the `print` I'm afraid.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen wow, how did i miss that lmao

Comment: [232 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY4/C4MwEMX3foojSwyEDP3nUELpVpdOHV3UXqpQY6iRKuJntxftUjh497jfO54bfNnY3TznspAojeZpH8dckhzNIvF2dQXfYI9FZLjTbsSpsv7kInbF0UxhikkpBVhKGPOpJFtDG6SjI8X3kMCTYoj@zERIXggdsFWQ9oeYQDr@UMUqA5V1nY@EWn/TTyQgEloz2v9wFiq0yG6hA9zLzEPV2pT7pQm5BGrMrFdMcDHPn@b9enwB).

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>208</s> <s>205</s> 202 bytes

```c
a[];main(){puts("He\x6c\x6c\x6f... eh, \x77h\x6fm sh\x6fu\x6c\x64 I g\162eet?");gets(a);puts((*a|'    ')^1819438967|(a[1]|32)^100?"N\x6f. That isn't \x77hat I meant.":"Ah, yes. \x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64.");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU5NC4JAEP0rw15coxa/cjUPEnTIS126qcGybCqkRK5kZL/dRquBYZg3b957clVIOY4izaNaVA01X7dOt5TsVdb78tcXxhiocglZz3k5ATW08@x@DA8SKDLbd5TSMTGjQqGIMKNZjC7EYACWYZ7twA49Nwh9PlCR2vngOghaVkwOsxGcSqGhahtDf91wS6BWotGMbMgWQzxVy/C25tMDcpx/BobG73F8HO/X3Qc)

Apparently you don't even have to specify an array length. Ungolfed:

```c
int a[];                  // Array of ints. Hint: ints are 4 characters wide.

main(){
    puts("Hello... eh, whom should I greet?");
    gets(a);              // Read input line.
    puts(
        (*a | '    ')     // Tolower() the first four characters
            ^ 1819438967  // Compare to "worl", non-zero if not the same
        | (a[1] | 32)     // Tolower() the fifth character
            ^ 100         // Compare to "d\0\0\0", non-zero if not the same
        ?                 // If non-zero bits present, it wasn't "world".
            "No. That isn't what I meant."
        :                 // Otherwise, we have a match.
            "Ah, yes. World.");
}
```

Thanks to @ceilingcat for shaving off 3 bytes.

Comment: @ceilingcat That's fantastic, I didn't know multi-character character literals would actually work as expected! It's too bad that `'lrow'` is odd, otherwise I could probably have created another four-character literal that doesn't contain those letters but that I could multiply by 2.