# Swapping "Good" and "Bad"

Tags: code-golf, string

**Challenge Description:**

Write a program that asks the user for input. The user will enter `Good` or `Bad`. You do not have to support any other input. If the user enters `Good`, print `Bad` and vice versa (to stdout etc).

**Notes:**

*1)* You cannot use any other pair of two words.

*2)* Your program only has to ask and print once.

*3)* You do not need to display prompt string.

*4)* The output must appear separated from the input by any means.

*5)* No function is allowed accepting the value and returning the result; User must interact with the program.

*Good luck!*

Comment: May we write a function that takes input as argument instead of prompting for it?

Comment: Congratulations on your first challenge. I've removed the [tag:code-challenge] tag, as it is only to be used for indicating alternative scoring criteria (*not* [tag:code-golf]). I look forward to seeing interesting challenges from you, but consider using [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/43319) to design your challenges, at least the first few times.

Comment: Please edit your question about whether a function is allowed or not. I would highly recommend not restricting input to STDIN, unless you have a very good reason to (and I can't see one)

Comment: *asks the user for input (stdin etc)* shows that only STDIN or interactive input is allowed. Please change this to all default I/O methods

Comment: "Asks the user for input", should that be some explicit question? Because an empty CLI prompt isn't really asking for anything …

Comment: What is the purpose for this restriction? *No function is allowed accepting the value and returning the result; User must interact with the program*

Answer (score 53):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>32</s>  31 bytes

```python
exit('GBoaodd'['G'<input()::2])
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7Uis0RD3d0pPzE/JUU9Wt1d3SYzr6C0REPTysooVvP/f6fEFAA)**

#### How?

Tests if input is `'Good'` by comparing `'G'<input()`.

Uses the fact that in Python `False==0` and `True==1` to use the result as the `start` index of a slice of `'GBoaodd'` using an undefined `stop` and a `step` of `2` with `'GBoaodd'[start:stop:step]`.

Prints to STDERR (saving a byte with `exit` in place of `print`).

Comment: What a trick! Can't understand how this works.

Comment: Can you use a lambda to shorten bytes?

Comment: @MilkyWay90 As per the question it must be a program accepting input.

Comment: @A__ by default yes, although there is a comment by OP which suggests it could be overruled here.

Comment: @A__ OP has confirmed that printing to stderr is fine

Comment: Too bad that "Good" and "Bad" share a "d", or you could do `'GoodBad'.strip(input())` which is a byte shorter.

Answer (score 20):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program that prompts for input from stdin and prints to stdout.

```apl
'GooBad'~¯1↓⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L@6e36@U2KKet2h9YaP2iY/6p0HEv@vAAYFXEDZFC4YB6gOAA)

`⍞` prompt for input from stdin; `Good` or `Bad`

`¯1↓` drop the last character (`d`); `Goo` or `Ba`

`'GooBad'~` multiset subtract those characters from these; `Bad` or `Good`

Comment: Why the downvote‽

Comment: Does the code have `GooBad` or `GoodBad`?

Comment: I think it should have ```GooBad```, as adding a character ```d`` will make this post 14 bytes.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 13):

### bash, 20 bytes

```bash
sed s/$1//<<<GoodBad
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RaFYX8VQX9/GxsY9Pz/FKTHl////QBIA)

Answer (score 11):

## [Turing Machine But Way Worse](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/Turing-Machine-But-Way-Worse), 405 bytes

```
0 0 0 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 2 0 0
0 2 0 1 3 0 0
0 3 0 1 4 0 0
0 4 0 1 5 0 0
1 5 0 1 6 0 0
0 5 1 1 h 0 0
1 6 1 1 7 0 0
1 7 0 1 8 1 0
0 8 0 1 9 0 0
1 9 1 1 9 0 0
0 9 0 1 a 0 0
1 a 0 1 a 0 0
0 a 0 0 b 0 0
0 b 1 1 c 1 0
0 c 0 0 d 0 0
1 d 0 0 e 0 0
0 e 0 0 f 0 0
0 f 1 1 g 1 1
1 h 1 1 i 0 0
0 i 1 1 j 1 0
0 j 0 1 k 0 0
1 k 1 1 k 0 0
0 k 0 1 l 0 0
0 l 1 1 l 0 0
1 l 1 0 m 1 0
1 m 1 1 n 1 0
1 n 1 1 o 0 0
0 o 0 1 p 1 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBbDoMgFET/uwqWIPXJCroOH7VVUPrRxOVTOc5HcxMmx5k7GL7bcBwpFSaPPefUmzXX3KECtaYUlVAlqqBaezXUyKtpectroFbUkuzyjWeyg5w8R9KpxeH18vo/Ki41g2hgb1TniDdpDzVPJVEzi2b2Xvm85f/NtMhboFWdK7d7dXo8r6THC6KAF5QMvOxGi0Wt2UU7FLUXafnkbyk9Ypx@)

Well, this took a while.

**UNFINISHED EXPLANATION**:

```
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 Start going to the sixth bit
1 1 1 1 2 0 0
0 2 0 1 3 0 0
0 3 0 1 4 0 0
0 4 0 1 5 0 0 End going to the sixth bit
1 5 0 1 6 0 0 If the sixth bit is 1, then it is Good. Start transforming "G" to "B" and go to state 6
0 5 1 1 h 0 0 Else, it is Bad. Start transforming "B" to "G" and go to state h
1 6 1 1 7 0 0 Keep on transforming "G" to "B"
1 7 0 1 8 1 0 End transforming and print "B"
0 8 0 1 9 0 0 We are in the first "o" in "Good". Start moving into the 5th bit.
1 9 1 1 9 0 0
0 9 0 1 a 0 0
1 a 0 1 a 0 0 Do some looping magic and start transforming "o" to "a"
0 a 0 0 b 0 0 End looping magic
0 b 1 1 c 1 0 End transforming and print "a"
0 c 0 0 d 0 0 
1 d 0 0 e 0 0 Start transforming "a" to "d"
0 e 0 0 f 0 0 
0 f 1 1 g 1 1 Stop transforming, print "d", and terminate
1 h 1 1 i 0 0 Continue transforming "B" to "G"
0 i 1 1 j 1 0 Stop transforming and print out "G"
0 j 0 1 k 0 0 Start going into position to print out "oo"
1 k 1 1 k 0 0
0 k 0 1 l 0 0 Move more efficiently using LOOPING MAGIC1!1111111 
0 l 1 1 l 0 0 looping magic end, start transforming
1 l 1 0 m 1 0 end transforming and print out out "o"
1 m 1 1 n 1 0 print out "o" again
1 n 1 1 o 0 0 get into the "d" byte
0 o 0 1 p 1 1 print "d" and execute YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

Comment: "Turing-Machine-But-Way-Worse" is, without a doubt, my new favorite esolang.

Comment: @MikeTheLiar Thanks!

Comment: "YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED" ArnoldC, is that you?

Comment: @TemporalWolf It is I, ArnoldC!

Comment: @A__ It isn't actually ArnoldC; I just put the exit command as a comment as a joke

Answer (score 8):

## 8088 Assembly, IBM PC DOS, 25 bytes

**Unassembled:**

```
BA 0110     MOV  DX, OFFSET GB  ; point DX to 'Good','Bad' string 
D1 EE       SHR  SI, 1          ; point SI to DOS PSP (80H) 
02 04       ADD  AL, [SI]       ; add input string length to AL, set parity flag 
7B 02       JNP  DISP           ; if odd parity, input was 'Bad' so jump to display 'Good'
02 D0       ADD  DL, AL         ; otherwise add string length as offset for 'Bad' string 
        DISP: 
B4 09       MOV  AH, 9          ; DOS display string function 
CD 21       INT  21H            ; call DOS API, write string to console 
C3          RET                 ; return to DOS 
        GB  DB  'Good$','Bad$'
```

**Explanation:**

Looks at the length of input string (plus leading space) that DOS stores at memory address `80H`, and adds it to `AL` (initially `0` [by DOS](http://www.fysnet.net/yourhelp.htm)).  If there is an odd number of `1` bits in the binary representation of the string length, the CPU parity flag is set to odd, and vice-versa.  So input string `' Bad'` length `4` (`0000 0100`), is odd parity and input string `' Good'` is `5` (`0000 0101`) is even parity.

`DX` is initially set to point to the string `'Good$Bad$'`, and if parity is even (meaning input was `' Good'`) advance the string pointer by that length (`5`) so it now points to `'Bad$'`.  If parity is odd, do nothing since it already points to `'Good$'`.  Then use DOS API to display a `$` terminated string to console.

**Example:**

[image]

Download and test [GOODBAD.COM](https://stage.stonedrop.com/ppcg/GOODBAD.COM) or build from `xxd` dump:

```
0000000: ba10 01d1 ee02 047b 0202 d0b4 09cd 21c3  .......{......!.
0000010: 476f 6f64 2442 6164 24                   Good$Bad$
```

Answer (score 7):

### Python 3, <del>38</del> <del>37</del> <del>34</del> 33 bytes

```
exit("C">input()and"Good"or"Bad")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7Uis0RDyVnJLjOvoLREQzMxL0XJPT8/RSm/SMkpMUVJ8/9/EBcA)

`exit()` : returns an exit code as output

`"C">input()` : Checks whether the input is larger than the string `C` in the alphabetical order

`and"Good"` : If the result is `True`, then returns with `Good`

`or"Bad"` : Otherwise, returns with `Bad`

Comment: 34: [`print("C">input()and"Good"or"Bad")`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ8lZyS4zr6C0REMzMS9FyT0/P0Upv0jJKTFFSfP/fxAXAA)

Comment: `exit(input()[3:]and"Bad"or"Good")` also works for the same byte count.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“Ċ³ṫ³»œṣ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//4oCcxIrCs@G5q8KzwrvFk@G5o////0JhZA)**

A full program expecting a Python formatted string as an argument

#### How?

```
“Ċ³ṫ³»œṣ - Main Link: list of characters, S
“Ċ³ṫ³»   - compression of dictionary words "Good"+"Bad" = ['G','o','o','d','B','a','d']
      œṣ - split on sublists equal to S
         - implicit, smashing print
```

Comment: Looks like OP responded, input isn't restricted to STDIN.

Answer (score 6):

## C, <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```c
main(){puts("Good\0Bad"+getchar()%6);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oLSkWEPJPT8/JcbAKTFFSTs9tSQ5I7FIQ1PVTNO69v9/oCAA)

Saved one byte thanks to @tsh.

Comment: `main(){puts("Good\0Bad"+getchar()%6);}` 38 bytes

Comment: Shouldn't you add `#include<stdio.h>`?

Comment: @polfosolఠ_ఠ If this were anything but code golf, you *should*, but in C89, you can [implicitly declare functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508503/is-implicit-function-declaration-legal-in-c89).

Comment: Can you use a null byte instead of `\0`?

Answer (score 6):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 72 bytes

```
,>+++++>,>,>,>,[<<<<[-<->>---<]<.>>+.>>.>>>]<[<<<[-<+>>+++<]<.>>-..>.>>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fx04bBOx0IDDaBgiidW107ex0dXVtYm307Oy0gRiI7GJtoiGS2nYgTRBJXT09kGTs//9OiSlc/wE)

Explanation:
,>+++++>,>,>,>,

Read either: 
"G", 5, "o", "o", "d" or
"B", 5, "a", "d", 0

[<<<<[-<->>---<]<.>>+.>>.>>>]
If the last character is not zero:

Substract 5 from the first cell once and from the third cell thrice.
Increment cell 3

Output cells 1, 3, 5.

<[<<<[-<+>>+++<]<.>>-..>.>>]

Otherwise add 5 to the first cell once and to the third cell thrice.

Decrement cell 3

Output cells 1, 3, 3, 4

Comment: That's a nice solution. You can shorten it a little bit by not using a newline in the input.

    ,>+++++>,>,>,[<<<[-<->>---<]<.>>+.>>.>>]<[<<[-<+>>+++<]<.>>-..>.>]

Comment: yeah, I realized that there is something to optimise there, but I found it hard to interpret what is necessary to comply with rule 4

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>42</s> <s>37</s> <s>35</s> 32 bytes

-10 thanks to Giuseppe and AkselA!

```r
`if`(scan(,'')>'C','Bad','Good')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyEzLUGjODkxT0NHXV3TTt1ZXUfdKTEFSLrn56eoa/4HUf8B)

Comment: @Giuseppe that was quick. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I recognize a lot of the other R golfers' names, so I often click on posts if I see their name as the most recent. :-)

Comment: using `"C"` instead of the first `"Bad"` as in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187888/67312) will save another couple bytes.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would something like `\`if\`(readline()>"C","Bad","Good")` be a valid answer? I'm new to this game and its rules.

Comment: @AkselA yes, but I'd also suggest using `scan(,"")` instead of `readline()`. Feel free to come to [golfR](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81960/golfr), the R golf chatroom if you have any R-specific questions :-)

Comment: @AkselA also see [Tips for Golfing in R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4024/tips-for-golfing-in-r) for some specific tips; there are hidden gems in there if you read them :-)

Answer (score 5):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>21 16</s>  13 bytes

*Thanks @Cowsquack for the hints.*

```
/B/cGood
cBad
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1jfPT9f3ylR37qEqxhEg7j//wPJFC6nxBQA)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1jfKVHfPT9f37qEK9kpMeX/fyAnhQvIAgA)</s>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/X99JP9k9Pz@FK9kpMeX/fzATyAIA)

TIL `c` will short-circuit the current line's parsing.

Comment: `c` offers a shorter solution

Comment: You can still save 3 more bytes using `c`

Comment: Had to play around with it a bit, but I figured it out!

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 10 bytes

```
:`GoodBad
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3yrBPT8/xSkxhev/fyAJAA)

`:` swaps the input and the regex, so this computes `'GoodBad'.replace(input, '')`.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <s>36</s> 34 bytes

```
interact g
g"Bad"="Good"
g _="Bad"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZZxvzPzOvJLUoMblEIZ0rXckpMUXJVsk9Pz9FiStdId4WLPD/P5D8l5yWk5he/F83uaAAAA)

Edit: -2 bytes thanks to @cole

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZZxvzPzOvJLUoMblEIZ0rXckpMUXJVsk9Pz9FiStdId4WLPD/P5D8l5yWk5he/F83uaAAAA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript 31 bytes

I like Arnauld's answer, but I would like it to accept user input and be runnable on StackExchange like so:

```js
alert(prompt()[3]?'Bad':'Good')
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 582 bytes

(Whitespace added for readability)

```
G.Ajax,.Puck,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Puck]Ajax:
Open mind.Be you nicer the sum ofa big cat the cube ofa big big cat?If solet usScene V.
You is the sum ofthe sum ofyou a big big cat a cat.Speak thy.You is the sum ofyou twice twice twice the sum ofa big big cat a cat.Speak thy.Speak thy.You is the square oftwice the sum ofa big big cat a cat.Let usScene X.
Scene V:.Ajax:
You is the sum ofthe sum ofyou a big big pig a pig.Speak thy.You is the sum ofyou the sum ofa big big big big big cat a pig.Speak thy.You is the sum ofyou the sum ofa big cat a cat.
Scene X:.Ajax:Speak thy.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVBRCoJAEL3KHED2AP6EQoQQFAhSRB/rOpapq7m7lKe3XZXUMoo@dpiZnffmvRFl1jQr4lzo3SJbxVKLOEyCZxOfIUeTHJZcYgVmBCiPwEwdTWVvSuSQJzwiLkJdKOAJ05PyjCBUDkVMIUxOwKhse0yF@Gz2HwsvBlFkKEGJbmNA9popESOaITNLJnhd6Uj8EmmqEfU72EDkTQubxheNn@jmia@KVsbKL1zrkbddf9XAbi9u/@y01I@a@NXpjJbx63T9QTQ6TmeltzDQNI1Lowc)

I get the first letter of the input with `Open mind`. Then I need to determine what it is. Of all the numbers between `B`=66 and `G`=71, my brute forcer says 66 is the shortest to write (`the sum ofa big cat the cube ofa big big cat`), so I compare the first letter of the input to 66. Scene I continues to print `Good`, or Scene V prints `Bad`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
¿⁻ＬＳ³Ba¦Goo¦d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9jaGFyY29hbP//wr/igbvvvKzvvLPCs0JhwqZHb2/CpmT//0JhZA)

#### Explanation:

```
¿⁻ＬＳ³          If length of input minus 3 is truthy:
      Ba¦         print Ba
         Goo¦       else print Goo
             d        print d
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
"BadooGB"~-_#@,,<,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X8kpMSU/391JqU43XtlBR8dG5/9/oBAA)

*-2 bytes thanks to Jo King*

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 22 bytes

```ruby
->n{n>?F?"Bad":"Good"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOs/O3s1eySkxRclKyT0/P0Wp9n9BaUmxQlo0WDCWC8YDS8b@BwA)

Comment: The question does say "asks the user for input", but the shortest way to do that is replacing the lambda with `p gets` and so it's the same length. (my original comment said you could save 2 bytes, but I didn't account for printing the result)

Comment: If we're actually going to be talking about a full program asking user for input, using the `-p` flag would give the most efficient answer: `$_=$_>?F?:Bad:"Good"` is 20 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyXeViXezt7N3sopMcVKyT0/P0Xp/38Q9S@/oCQzP6/4v24BAA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
”‚¿‰±”áIK
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Emigna*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPcRw2zDu1/1LDh0EYg5/BCT@///50SUwA) or [verify both test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@oYe6jhlmH9j9q2HBoI5CjXFZpr6TwqG2SgpI9huThhZXe/3X@AwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
”‚¿‰±”     # Push dictionary string "Good Bad"
      á    # Only keep letters (to remove the space)
       IK  # Remove the input
           # (output the result implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210), to understand why `”‚¿‰±”` is `"Good Bad"`.

Comment: I can see many alternate variations on this, but they all end up at the same byte count :(

Comment: Actually, you can save a byte with `á`.

Comment: @Emigna Ah of course, brilliant. Now that I see `á` I can't believe I hadn't thought about it, but at the same time I know I would have never thought about it. ;) Thanks! (And yeah, I had a few 10-byte alternatives as well.)

Comment: Don't even need á, `”‚¿Bad”IK` is also a 9.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <strike>30</strike> 28 bytes

```
puts %w|Good Bad|-gets.split
```

Not the golf-iest, but I like the abuse of split to remove the trailing newline and convert to an array in one call.

EDIT -2 bytes thanks to Value Ink's suggestion!

Comment: This prints `"Good"` or `"Bad"` (with quotes); I'm not sure that's allowed.

Comment: Abuse the fact that `puts` prints each element of an array on a separate line. It's 3 bytes more expensive than `p`, but it evens out since you take out the `[0]` and then save 2 more bytes by no longer needing parens. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFhBtbzGPT8/RcEpMaVGNz21pFivuCAns@T/f6AAAA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: @ValueInk thanks! Jordan's issue also gets resolved by this change so it's a win-win.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 124 bytes

```java
interface G{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).next().length()>3?"Bad":"Good");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxCsIwEEB/JWRKBrO4KSi49AMySocjOevF9iLptSql3x4ruD0ej5dghl2Kj1qJBcsNAqpmGQWEgpozRTUAsfFSiLtrC3bxn1FwcHkS99ykGMaXStvGTUK98wGYsZh/Rmwd41uMdT1yJ3djT/uzvkDUB93kHLU9rmutP/wC)

Most likely, there‘s still some room for improvement, but I‘m entirely new to code golfing.

Comment: Welcome! Consider adding an explanation and/or a link to an online interpreter where you can run your code. (See other answers for examples.) Code-only answers tend to be automatically flagged as low-quality.

Comment: The length part could just be `!="Bad"`

Comment: [109 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcrBCsIwDADQXyk9tQeLN0EFQZB9wI7DQ2iqZrJktHEqY99eFbw@Xg8TrHq810qsKV8gJtPMRUEpmkkIzQDErtVMfO3O4PWW5VnM6RXTqCQ8t@@iaQjy0DB@k7o/EIecAJ3fb9YH24ig3dojoPW7Zan1Bx8)

Answer (score 3):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 11 bytes

```
"GoodBad"\/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X8k9Pz/FKTFFKUb//38gDQA)

### Explanation

```
"GoodBad"   # Define the lookup table "GoodBad"
         \  # Swap the input so that it can be used by /
          / # Split the lookup table by occurences of the input
            # Implicit print, smashing
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>35</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [@xigoi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98955)

-1 byte thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323)

```js
alert(prompt()[3]?'Bad':'Good')
```

Comment: -3 bytes: `prompt()<'G'`

Comment: `prompt()[3]` enough

Answer (score 3):

## C (gcc), 48 bytes

```
main(){puts(getchar()-66?"Bad":"Good");}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7842jLWOjcxM09Ds7qgtKRYo7ikKDm3QCM9FcTW1FFySkxR0rQHU1ZK7vn5QJ517f//AA)

The program only actually takes one character as input, although `getchar` reads until a newline is found unlike `getch` which only *lets* you input a single character. It checks if there's a difference between that character and the ascii code for 'B' (66), printing "Bad" if there is and "Good" if there isn't.

Comment: Taking just one character as input is perfectly valid, and is in fact what most other answers are doing

Comment: @mousetail Thanks, I edited my answer to remove the question :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
çEF♫a║▬h
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8745460e61ba1668&i=Good%0ABad&a=1&m=2)

<s>Essentially `replace("BadGood", input, "")`.</s>

Multiset xor with "GooBa".  Algorithm copied verbatim from [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187826/527)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
“GooBa”œ^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rwxz3/HynxEcNc49Ojvv//z@QlwIA)

#### Explanation

Multiset symmetric difference between the input and the string `“GooBa”`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks. Edited

Comment: I don't see any indication that the input has to come through STDIN...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Unfortunately the whole way the question is written implies we must have a program which, when run, *asks* for input (even though no prompt must be displayed). See the OPs own answer too. If you want to get them to change it go for it (although do note that they haven't answered the first, similar although slightly different, question in the comments)

Comment: Looks like OP responded, input isn't restricted to STDIN.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thanks! Rolled back

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 20 bytes

```
oo
o
T`G\oaB`Ro
o
oo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/P58rnyskwT0mP9EpIQjEyc///989Pz@FyykxBQA) Link includes test suite. Explanation:

```
oo
o
```

Turn `Good` into `God`.

```
T`G\oaB`Ro
```

Transpose the letters `GoaB` with the reverse of that list, thus exchanging `G` with `B` and `o` with `a`, i.e. exchanging `God` with `Bad`.

```
o
oo
```

Turn `God` into `Good`.

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fPT@fq5DLKZELxgALpQAZKQA), but less creative

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
'Good','Bad'-ne$args
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/%23%23K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqRgq1D9X909Pz9FXUfdKTFFXTcvVSWxKL34fy0XlwZUQgEso6kDFAAxgHywuKZCjYKqQjWXgoJKgY6CSgXQLJV4EK8IyFJTABquUgDkKqloAOV0UwuBEppWQEKJq/Y/AA)

*-2 bytes thanks to mazzy*

Comment: [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqRgq1D9X909Pz9FXUfdKTFFXTcvVSWxKL34fy0XlwZUQgEso6kDFAAxgHywuKZCjYKqQjWXgoJKgY6CSgXQLJV4EK8IyFJTABquUgDkKqloAOV0UwuBEppWQEKJq/Y/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 30 bytes

```java
s->s.charAt(0)>66?"Bad":"Good"
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##dYyxDoIwFEV3vuKFqR1onBgkYnTAyYnRODxbqkVoSVtIDOHba4msTvcm99zT4oRZK96Bd@gcXFFpmBOlfWMl8gaqufZW6SdIshVHiyUZxkenODiPPsZklIA@Xjfmdge0T0ejqQIJh@Cy0jH@QnvyZEfLPD@mZxTpPr0YI9JQJPXH@aZnZvRsiAbfaSKZJL@d0v/Aqln3ZQlf)

Comment: How does it take input from the user (e.g. by reading from stdin) and print the result (instead of just returning it)?

Comment: @nimi OP hasn't specified whether IO includes arguments and returns. By default, it is allowed

Comment: "ask the user for input" sounds like reading the input from stdin (or equivalent) to me. "print" usually means print to stdout (or equivalent). To my understanding the IO defaults are overwritten.

Comment: @nimi I can argue a missing argument error is a prompt. As for output, you do have a point.

Comment: You can take the inputs as character-arrays, which is allowed by default for strings, to change `s.charAt(0)` to `s[0]`: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY2xDoIwFEV3vuKlUzvQODFIxKgJTk6MhOEJFItASVtICOHbaw2jcbrDPefeFmcM2@rtyg6NgQfKAdZADrbWAssa0jWzWg4NCFq@UOcFGBZvwTg9O1mCsWh9zEpW0HuV7rCnUDeG@aUUBJycCROTH4okis7kihU5krtSFXFxkC3G1j1Xk@WjV203UMEF3Xtu1c2fXrTGhTLG/uPf0V9629wH).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 15 bytes

```perl
$_=/B/?Good:Bad
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbfSd/ePT8/xcopMeX/fxDrX35BSWZ@XvF/3QIA)

Comment: Just revisited this. Abusing flags as usual `-0144l`, you can save the `d`s! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbfSd/ePT/fyinx/38gnfIvv6AkMz@v@L9ugYGhiUkOAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 24 bytes

```
=IF(A1>"C","Bad","Good")
```

Using @MilkyWay90's `<C` suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>26</del> 23 bytes

A ternary is just cheaper:

```php
<?=$argn==Bad?Goo:Ba?>d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WJbEoPc/W1ikxxd49P9/KKdHeLuX/fyAz5V9@QUlmfl7xf103AA)

**Original answer, 26 bytes**

```php
<?=[Ba,Goo][$argn==Bad]?>d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt422ilRxz0/PzZaJbEoPc/W1ikxJdbeLuX/f6Bgyr/8gpLM/Lzi/7puAA)

**Or 21 bytes (but this is basically [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187816/swapping-good-and-bad/187836#187836))**

```php
<?=$argn[3]?Ba:Goo?>d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WJbEoPS/aONbeKdHKPT/f3i7l/38gnfIvv6AkMz@v@L@uGwA)

Comment: Judging by the phrasing of the question, `readline()` is likely more appropriate than `$argn`.

Answer (score 2):

### [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg), 22 bytes

```
?^_^_o=[^aB^_|^ooG^]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 52 bytes

```
,>,,<<,[>-----.<---.+++.<<]>[+++++.+[-<-->]<-..>>.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fx05Hx8ZGJ9pOFwT0bECEtra2no1NrF20NgjoaUfrAoXtYm109fTs7PTsYv//d8/PTwEA)

Relies on Bad being one letter shorter than Good, so the last input is empty.

#### Explanation:

```
,>,,<<,       Get input into the first three cells
[             If the last letter was not empty (i.e. Good)
 >-----.      Decrement 'G' to 'B' and print
 <---.        Decrement 'd' to 'a' and print
 +++.         Increment back to 'd' and print
>>]           End loop
>[            If it is Bad instead
 +++++.       Increment 'B' to 'G' and print
 +[-<-->]<-.. Manipulate into  'o' and print twice
 >>.          Print 'd'
>]            End loop
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-rt` <s>20</s> <s>17</s> <s>15</s> <s>13</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes (SBCS)

```
-᠀‘5ƳP↫
```

Transpiles to:

```
from KegLib import *
from Stackd import Stack
stack = Stack()
printed = False
iterable(stack, 'GoodBad')
string_input(stack)
maths(stack, '-')

if not printed:
    printing = ""
    for item in stack:
        if type(item) in [str, Stack]:
            printing += str(item)
        elif type(item) == Coherse.char:
            printing += item.v

        elif item < 10 or item > 256:
            printing += str(item)
        else:
            printing += chr(item)
    print(printing)
```

It's a port of the 05AB1E answer. Essentially, it:

- Pushes the string `"GoodBad"`
- Takes input as a string
- Subtracts the input from the pushed string. This works by replacing the first instance of the input within `GoodBad` with nothing.
- Implicitly prints the resulting string.
- The `-rt` flag tells Keg to read tokens from right to left.

### Answer History

```
?G=[øBad|ø‘5Ƴ
```

Transpiles to the following:

```
from KegLib import *
from Stackd import Stack
stack = Stack()
printed = False
Input(stack)
character(stack, 'G')
comparative(stack, '=')
if bool(stack.pop()):
    empty(stack)
    character(stack, 'B')
    character(stack, 'a')
    character(stack, 'd')

else:
    empty(stack)
    iterable(stack, 'Good')

if not printed:
    printing = ""
    for item in stack:
        if type(item) is Stack:
            printing += str(item)

        elif type(item) is str:
            printing += custom_format(item)
        elif type(item) == Coherse.char:
            printing += item.v

        elif item < 10 or item > 256:
            printing += str(item)
        else:
            printing += chr(item)
    print(printing)
```

#### Explanation

```
?G=[øBad|ø‘5Ƴ

?            #Get input from user
 G=          #If the first letter is "G"
   [øBad     #Clear the stack and push "Bad"
        |    #Else,
         ø‘5Ƴ#Clear the stack and push the compressed string "Good"
```

Comment: Wonderful, I could not golf to that length... I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: @A__ just as i have up voted yours

Comment: My answer is a lot worse than yours. You should not have upvoted my answer...

Comment: Is there any up to date keg documentation?

Comment: @EdgyNerd not really. It's been a while since I updated the docs. Most information about new things can be found in the chat/[here](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/blob/master/Information_noblank.pdf)

Comment: @EdgyNerd a lot of things have changed recently: strings are now a thing, more data types and so much more

Comment: @EdgyNerd, also there is some information [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg%2B_Language_Design), but note that some of it may be incorrect as a few things have changed since then

Answer (score 2):

## [Boolfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Boolfuck), <s>110</s> 68 bytes

```
,+;+[;+;;;;+;+;+;<;]>+;;[+;;;+;+;+;;;;+;+;;+;+;;;;+];+;;+;;;+;+;;+;;
```

Thanks to Jo King for the massively improved solution!

[Try it with Online!](https://tio.run/##S8rPz0krTc7@/19H21o72lrbGgi0wdDGOtYOyI3WhotAGXB2LIQDF7X@/989Pz8FAA)

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8rPz0krTc7@/19H21o72lrbGgi0wdDGOtYOyI3WhotAGXB2LIQDF7X@/989Pz8FAA). I think it can be better though

Comment: Wow, how were you able to save so many bytes over my answer?

Answer (score 2):

## [Boolfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/boolfuck), 47 bytes

```
+>,+;>,;,+;>;;;+;+;+[;<;;;,;+;;+;<];;+;+;;+;;+;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8rPz0krTc7@/1/bTkfb2k7HGkRaW1trg2C0tQ2QqQNkApFNLEQUgv7/d0pMAQA)

Uses the fact that you can basically just take in the input as bits and then invert certain bits to turn it into the opposite letter.

#### Explanation:

```
+>,+;>,;,+;>;;;+;+;+    Print the first letter by inverting the first and third bits of the input
                        'B' = 01000010
                        'G' = 11100010
                        This leaves the tape as
                            1 1 1 1' in the case of Bad
                            1 0 0 1' in the case of Good
                        By making the center cells the inverted bits
[;<;;;,;+;;+;<]         Print the center letters by looping over the two pairs of cells
                        0 1' results in 'a' = 10000110
                        1 1' results in 'o' = 11110110 by printing the 1 in the 2-4th places
                        1 1 1 1' loops twice, while 1 0 0 1' only loops once
;;+;+;;+;;+;            Finally print 'd' = 00100110
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

***-1** by just defining a variable first instead of using an empty fallback*

```sh
x=GoodBad
<<<${x/$1}
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGpVql2krXPT8/xSkxpVZfxbD2////QCYA)</s>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/2NY9Pz/FKTGFy8bGRqW6WF/FsPb///9AAQA)

```sh
<<<${${[implicit parameter]:-fallback}/pattern[/implicit empty replacement]}
```

No coreutils, and nearly as good as the [Bash+coreutils answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187832/86147) (which is compatible with Zsh).

Comment: Why not `x=GoodBad;<<<${x/$1}`?

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <s>114</s> <s>104</s> 103 bytes

```
(much whitespace)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzRCYBADEO/kymyzc0heuB9naDg@DUtamlD@hp67@Pq57GsPUISQFFuEF6QSGUteclBFZ3kSyrK39nz40plPSpGRrQ5twc)

-5 bytes thanks to Jo King.

-5 bytes by determining if the input is odd or even instead of subtracting "B"

-1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen by using the initial 3 as address for reading characters

```
sssttl      push "d"
sls         dup (address for "retrieve")
sls         dup (address for "readc")
tlts        readc
ttt         retrieve
ssstsl      push 2
tstt        mod (determine if input is even or odd)
ltssl       jz good
sssl        push "a"
ssttttttl   push "B"
lsll        jmp print
lsssl       lbl good
ssstttsl    push "o"
sls         dup
sstttstsl   push "G"

lssl        lbl print
sssttsssstl 97
tsss        add
tlss        printc
lsll        jmp print
```

Comment: -1 byte by replacing the `sssl` (push 0) with `sls` (dupe the 3 that's used to print "d"). Also a minor error in your explanation: the `sssttl - push 2` should be either `sssttl - push 3` or `ssstsl - push 2` (both result in `0` for `B`, and either 1 or 2 for `G`, so the program would be correct in both cases). Alternatively for `sssttl - push 3`, you could dupe the initial 3 a third time and use a swap after retrieving the input, but that unfortunately results in the same byte-count (repushing 3 or duplicating + swapping are both 6 bytes).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have the idea to use the 3 as address for the `readc-retrieve` command. The `push 2` was really intended to be a push 2. I wanted to determine if the first input character was even or odd, so I was just lucky it also worked with `sssttl`.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 30 bytes

```php
<?=strtok(BaGoo,readline()).d;
```

Best suppress notices.

Comment: There is already a shorter PHP answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187930/81663

Comment: @Night2, reading the question as waiting on a prompt, a readline solution seemed more appropriate as an answer.

Comment: @Night2, but granted if they were to swap $argn for readline(), theirs would still be a shorter solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 30 bytes

```cs
Write(Read()>'B'?"Bad":"Good")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/vCizJFUjKDUxRUPTTt1J3V7JKTFFyUrJPT8/RUnz/38gDwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 52 bytes

```
fun main()=print("GoodBad".replace(readLine()!!,""))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/8/rTRPITcxM09D07agKDOvREPJPT8/xSkxRUmvKLUgJzE5VaMoNTHFJzMvVUNTUVFHSUlT8/9/oDwA)

Comment: What does the `!!` operator do?

Comment: `!!` asserts that a nullable value is not null, effectively casting it down from `T?` to `T` or throwing a runtime error if it's `null`. `replace` doesn't accept `String?` but that's what `readLine()` returns so I have to assert it's not null (since it never will be per the challenge.)

Answer (score 2):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 59 bytes

```
%|~88W7MA{88W7M;99W65WM!;;25W25WW;}<88W2M;99W44WM;25W25WW;>
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%25%7C%7E88W7MA%7B88W7M%3B99W65WM!%3B%3B25W25WW%3B%7D%3C88W2M%3B99W44WM%3B25W25WW%3B%3E&input=Bad)

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript 50 bytes**

```js
alert((305786-parseInt(prompt(),26)).toString(26))
```

Comment: Please add what language you answer uses and a short description of how it functions

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 7 bytes

```
`ƛ⁋«Ṫ`-
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%60%C6%9B%E2%81%8B%C2%AB%E1%B9%AA%60-&inputs=Good&header=&footer=)

This is irony in a nutshell.

### Explained

```
`...`-
`...`  # the string "GoodBad"
     - # ^ - input (removes it)
```

In the spirit of my Keg answer, here's the compiled code:

```python
global stack, register, printed, output, MAP_START, MAP_OFFSET, _join, _vertical_join, use_encoding, input_level, raw_strings, retain_items, reverse_args, this_function
stack.append("GoodBad")

rhs, lhs = pop(stack, 2); stack.append(subtract(lhs, rhs))
```

Answer (score 2):

## .COM, 31 bytes

```
org 0x100
mov dx, 0x100
mov eax, 0xA20 + '$$'*0x10000
int 0x21
inc dx
inc dx
xor dword [0x102], 'Good' xor ('Bad'+0x0d000000)
mov al, 0x20
int 0x29     ; Avoid "Badd"
mov ah, 9
int 0x21
ret
```

Answer (score 1):

**My shortest possible solution in Python (43 bytes)**

```
print({'Good':'Bad','Bad':'Good'}[input()])
```

**And MilkyWay90 further golfed version (-2 bytes)**

```
print({'G':'Bad','B':'Good'}[input()[0]])
```

Comment: Normally, we recommend leaving challenges up for a while (I generally give it a week) before self-answering.

Comment: @Adám Good suggestion.

Comment: `print({'G':'Bad','B':'Good'}[input()[0]])` works too for -2 bytes

Comment: `print(['Bad','Good'][input()<'C'])` works for 34 bytes (-9)

Comment: @MilkyWay90 You're genius!

Comment: You should edit the answer then if you feel as though it is similar enough to your answer to be golfed down to.

Comment: @MilkyWay90 May I edit with your first suggestion or second? Second one is completely different solution.

Comment: Probably my first one; the second one, as you said, is completely different

Comment: You probably should put the shortest solution as the one solution without any alternative solutions

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>48</s> <s>44</s> 38 bytes

```
If[$ScriptInputString=="Bad",Good,Bad]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98zLVolOLkos6DEM6@gtCS4pCgzL93WVskpMUVJxz0/P0UHyIr9/x9I/tctAEqWAAA)

-4 bytes thanks to  [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan): using symbols instead of strings as output

-6 bytes by removing `Print@`, which is implicit in the command-line version of WolframScript and can be simulated on TIO with the `-print` argument

Comment: I don't think it's only the I/O that's wrong (I don't know Mathematica very well though) - adding a `Print` exposes a problem with the strings I think: [TIO](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvJNozLdozr6C0JDrW1tbWKTFFxz0/P0UHyIiN/f8fSAEA) (the `?` is, no doubt the prompt for input)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I couldn't make it work with TIO either; what I've given runs fine in Mathematica though. Note that there are no strings involved: `Good` and `Bad` are symbols here.

Comment: Ah symbols, right. Is it a full program, or just a snippet which can only run in a REPL (read–eval–print loop) (which is, I guess what you're running the code in)? I see no output command and I don't imagine Mathematica does any by default at the end of a program. Maybe a Mathematica expert can chime in...?

Comment: @JonathanAllan The previous version was a REPL tool for Mathematica. Now I've rewritten it as a command-line tool for wolframscript, using the proper i/o channels. This makes the code a lot longer though.

Comment: Nice. Maybe there are golfs to be had... :)

Comment: Looks like you could [use symbols for the output](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxMEzLVolOLkos6DEM6@gtCS4BCiabmur5JSYoqTjnp@fogNkxf7/D2L@BwA) to save 4.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 16 bytes

**Solution:**

```
$`Bad`Good"Bad"~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/XyXBKTElwT0/P0UJyFCqUwIz//8HAA)

Returns `"Good"` if input is `"Bad"` otherwise returns `"Bad"` for all other inputs.

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/XyXBKTElwT0/P0XJSSkz7/9/AA) with loose constraints

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 23 bytes

```cs
a=>a[0]>66?"Bad":"Good"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrgOh7BTSbBX@J9raJUYbxNqZmdkrOSWmKFkpuefnpyj9t@biCi/KLEn1ycxL1UjTgIhqalqjioJ0AAX/AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 23 bytes

```
/#Good/Bad//#Bad/Good/#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X1/ZPT8/Rd8pMUVfXxlEgrnK//8DAA)

There is no other way to take input in /// so it is hard-coded:

```
/#Good/Bad//#Bad/Good/#<INPUT HERE>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Windows batch, <del>53</del> <del>48</del> 47 bytes

-1 bytes, thanks to @Neil for noticing the trivialness of the space before `else`.

```
set/pa=
if %a%==Bad (echo Good)else (echo Bad)
```

`set/pa=` prompt for input and set a to that input

`if %a%==Bad (echo Good)else (echo Bad)` antonym for `Good` and `Bad`. Unfortunately Windows batch requires whitespace...

Comment: I think you can drop the space before `else` but no other spaces as you noticed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
+-"GooBa"z\d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1tXyT0/3ylRqSom5f9/IDMFAA)

```
+-"GooBa"z\d   Implicit: z=input()
 -"GooBa"z     Keep letters in "GooBa" which do not appear in z
+         \d   Append "d", implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 21 bytes

```
"Bad":i≠7*?~"Good"@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/1/JKTFFySrT9swOcy37OiX3/PwUJYf//0E0AA)

Prints `Good` when the input is `Bad` and prints `Bad` for all other inputs.

Answer (score 1):

## Sinclair ZX80 BASIC (4K ROM) - 46 tokenized BASIC bytes

```
 1 INPUT A$
 2 IF A$="GOOD" THEN PRINT "BAD"
 3 IF A$="BAD" THEN PRINT "GOOD"
```

#### Sinclair ZX81 BASIC (Also Timex TS 1000/1500 or ZX80 with 8K ROM upgrade) - 45 tokenized BASIC bytes

```
 1 INPUT A$
 2 PRINT "GOOD" AND A$="BAD";"BAD" AND A$="GOOD"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
print(['Bad','Good'][input()=='Bad'])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI1rdKTFFXUfdPT8/RT02OjOvoLREQ9PWFiwcq/n/PwA)

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI1rdKTFFXUfdPT8/RT02OjOvoLREQ9NG3V09VvP/fwA) by replacing ```input()=='Bad'``` with ```input()<'G'```

Answer (score 1):

## [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 16 bytes

```
(Bad)(Good)Bad^S
```

Since Underload has no input instructions, input is hard-coded (The ‘Bad’ on the right).

Really proud of this one: Underload has no way to check strings, so I had to go off of the fact the ‘Bad’ contains an `a`, which is an instruction that puts brackets around the top thing in the stack.

Edit: Saved 9 bytes over my old one by getting rid of 2 pairs of brackets, only using one `S` and getting rid of some `!`s and `^`s

[Try it with Bad!](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f9fwykxRVPDPT8/RRPIigv@/x8A)

[Try it with Good!](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f9fwykxRVPDPT8/RRNExAX//w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 38 bytes

```rkt
(write(match(read)['Bad'Good][_'Bad]))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Extended BrainFuck](http://ebf.sylwester.no/):  <s>29</s> 28

```
,>,,,[>|"Bad">>]<[>|"Good">]
```

*-1 bytes thanks to @JoKing*

The compiled bf code can run on an interpreter that expects stream end after the last letter and a interpreter that uses 0 as the EOF value. eg. `bf -n` or `beef`. eg

```
> bf ebf.bf < GoodBad.ebf > GoodBad.bf
> echo Bad | bf -n GoodBad.bf
Good
> echo Good | bf -n GoodBad.bf
Bad
```

Answer (score 1):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 20 bytes

```
Itj71m"Good"'Bad'ntp
```

I don't have it on TIO yet, I'll update this when I do.

Explanation:

```
It                   | Get input
  j71m           n   | If the first character is 'G'
      "Good"       p | - Print "Good"
            'Bad' tp | Else, print "Bad"
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Mzb@/9@zJMvcMFfJPT8/RUndKTFFPa@k4P9/IAMA "33 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 30 bytes

```
Fn.new{|x|"GooBa".trim(x)+"d"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xgq/DfLU8vL7W8uqaiRsk9P98pUUmvpCgzV6NCU1spRan2f3BlcUlqrl5BUWZeiQZIj15yYk6OhpJTYoqSpuZ/AA)

### Explanation

```
Fn.new{|x|                   } // New anonymous function with parameter x
                               // Sample input: "Bad"
          "GooBa"              // Define a string
                 .trim(x)      // Trim out all characters in the input string
                               // "GooBa" - "Bad" = "Goo"
                         +"d"  // Return the string joined with a "d": "Good"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) `d`, <del>12</del> <del>11</del> 9 bytes

Realized that I could use the implicit quote system. Still can't beat Keg with the decompression. (Alternative 9-byter:`§D⑺y⒁v⑼z¬`; but that's the same bytecount)

```
☺DΩy±v∞z↓
```

### Explanation

````
% Sample input: "Bad"
% Implicitly prepend a quote for this string
GooBa"     % Stack: ["Bad","GooBa"]
      S    % Stack: ["GooBa","Bad"]
       t   % "GooBa".trim("Bad"), which is "Goo"
        'd % Stack: ["Goo","d"]
           % Stack: ["Good"]

% Implicit output
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 17 bytes

```
.F`Goo`x?c`Ba`;H"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/1/PLcE9Pz@hwj45wSkxwdpD6f///0pAkRQlAA)

### Explanation:

```
                  \ Implicit: input on main stack.
.F                \ Pop last letter, and move to auxiliary stack.
  `Goo`           \ Push 'Goo' to main stack.
       x?     ;   \ If the stacks are equal:
         c`Ba`    \    Replace 'Goo' with 'Ba'
               H  \ Push 'd', as char(d) = 100 = H
                " \ Print stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 66 bytes

```
9a7m4a2x1v1x1f1r3x1v2l5s1o2d3m2s1o3a1o0x1x2f5a1o2d3m6a2o9s2s1o0x1f
```

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
9a7m4a2x1v                   # Set variable 1 equal to 67 ("C")
1x1f                         # Function 1
    1r3x1v2l                 # Read the first byte of input
                             # Jump to function 2 if it's less than variable 1 
            5s1o2d3m2s1o3a1o # Otherwise, output "Bad"

1x2f5a1o2d3m6a2o9s2s1o       # Function 2
                             # Output "Good"
1f                           # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) [`j`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends/14339#14339), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

Still doesn't tie with Keg. Help!

```
♥d←╖←I¡%
```

Uncompressed:

```
G'%Av%?S,
```

## Explanation

````
           % Implcitly start a compressed string
G'         % "good" in the dictionary
  %        % Capitalize
   Av      % "bad" in the dictionary
     %     % Capitalize
      ?    % End compressed string
       S   % Swap so that the input comes to the top
        ,  % Split the string on the input

Flag:j     % Implicit smash on output list
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [FALSE](https://github.com/somebody1234/FALSE), 23 bytes

```
^'B=$["Good"]?~["Bad"]?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0vMKU79/z9O3clWJVrJPT8/RSnWvi5aySkRxPj/HyQCAA)

### Explanation

The program gets an input character and checks if it is equal to 'B'. If it is, it prints 'Good', and if it isn't it prints 'Bad'. This makes use of the fact that 'Good' and 'Bad' are easily differentiable based on simply the first character of each word.

```
^                  {Get input character}
'B=                {See if input char is equal to 'B'}
["Good"]?~["Bad"]? {If top of stack is TRUE, print "Good", else print "Bad"}
```

Note: Curly brackets denote comments in FALSE. In the past I've used '//' to comment FALSE code in my explanations, but since it isn't syntactically valid  I'm now trying to use FALSE's comment syntax.

Answer (score 1):

## APOL, 32 bytes

Just checks if the input starts with "G".

`g(["Good" "Bad"] I(=(g(i) "G")))`

Answer (score 1):

## (e-)TeX, 48 bytes

```
\read0to~\expanded{\def\##1~{#1}}\#Good Bad \bye
```

Output is to dvi/pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 12 bytes

```
"GoodBad"RMq
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhZrlNzz81OcElOUgnwLIUJQmQVLQDIQNgA)

#### Explanation

```
           q  ; Read a line of input from stdin
         RM   ; Remove that substring from
"GoodBad"     ; This literal string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), 37 bytes

```
INPUT s$
IF"C"<s$THEN?"Bad"ELSE?"Good
```

Try it at [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack)

#### Explanation

Uses string comparison to separate the two cases. Ungolfed:

```
INPUT s$
IF "C" < s$ THEN PRINT "Bad" ELSE PRINT "Good"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 30 Bytes

```python
exit({'Good','Bad'}-{input()})
```

Uses the same `exit` trick as the other python 3 solution. It's unclear to me if this solution is necessarily allowed by the problem, but the output is certainly separated from the input, so I think it counts.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 29 bytes

```
read1 66 = "Good""Bad"? print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQma@QnVqUl5qjYP2/KDUxxVDBzEzBVkHJPT8/RUnJKTFFyV6hoCgzr@T/fyAHAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 105 bytes

```python
N
Count i while _/71 {
Write 66
Write 97
0
}
Count i while _ {
Write 71
Write 111
Write 111
0
}
Write 100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@Pyzm/NK9EIVOhPCMzJ1UhXt/cUKGaK7wosyRVwcwMyrA05zLgqkVXCldnbghlGBois0BaoDwDg///nRJTAA)

#### Explanation

```python
# Read a character from stdin (user must enter a full line)
N
# Loop while the character code int-divided by 71 is nonzero (i.e. G was entered)
Count i while _ / 71 {
  # Write Ba
  Write 66
  Write 97
  # Set accumulator to 0 to exit the loop
  0
}
# Loop while the accumulator is nonzero (i.e. previous loop did not run)
Count i while _ {
  # Write Goo
  Write 71
  Write 111
  Write 111
  # Set accumulator to 0 to exit the loop
  0
}
# Write d
Write 100
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$15\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 12.35 bytes

```
"Bad"Dz0=?"Good
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbrlZwSU5Rcqgxs7ZXc8_NTIKJQyQWLgZIQJgA)

```python
"Bad"Dz0=?"Good  # Implicit input
"Bad"D           # Push the string bad and duplicate           (STACK: "Bad", "Bad")
      z0         # Push the input                              (STACK: "Bad", "Bad", input)
        =?"Good  # If they are equal, push the string "Good"   (STACK: "Bad", "Good") IF input == "Bad"
                 # Otherwise, the stack is left as-is          (STACK: "Bad") IF input != "Bad"
                 # Implicit output of top of stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 24 bytes

```
$Good'$Bad^^Stdin[]|Echo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/X8U9Pz9FXcUpMSUuLrgkJTMvOrbGNTkj//9/kAQA)

### Explanation

```
$Good'$Bad^^Stdin[]|Echo
$Good'$Bad                   an array of the strings "Good" and "Bad"
          ^^                 remove from this array
            Stdin[]          standard input
                             this leaves us with a singleton array of the swapped element
                   |Echo     pipe the Echo function to each member of this array
                             (in this case, only prints the one element)
```

### Alternatives

**25 bytes:** `$Good'$Bad⩓Stdin[]|Echo`

**26 bytes:** `[$Good,$Bad]^^Stdin[]|Echo`

**29 bytes:** `Echo@If[Stdin[]@3,$Bad,$Good]`

**29 bytes:** `Echo@[$Bad,$Good][Stdin[]<$G]`

**37 bytes:** `[4875396,32943]^^STN@Stdin[]|Echo@NTS`

**44 bytes:** `Good:=$Bad;Bad:=$Good;Print@EvalHere@Stdin[]`

Answer (score 0):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>50</s> 35 bytes

Down to 35 thanks to @Expired Data

```fs
 fun a->if a>"B"then"Bad"else"Good"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv2fX5CapxBcWVySmmvNlZNaopBm@18hrTRPIVHXLjNNIdFOyUmpJCM1T8kpMUUpNac4Vck9Pz9F6b9zfl5xfk6qXnhRZkmqT2ZeqkaaBkwsKDUxBSykqanJpfAfpAEA)

Original:

[F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 50 bytes

```fs
printf(if stdin.ReadLine()>"B"then"Bad"else"Good")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/v6AoM68kTSMzTaG4JCUzTy8oNTHFJzMvVUPTTslJqSQjNU/JKTFFKTWnOFXJPT8/RUnz/38QDQA)

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv2fX5CapxBcWVySmmvNlZNaopBm@18hrTRPIVHXLjNNIdFOyUmpJCM1T8kpMUUpNac4Vck9Pz9F6b9zfl5xfk6qXnhRZkmqT2ZeqkaaBkwsKDUxBSykqanJpfAfpAEA "F# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 32 bytes

```python
print('Good','Bad')['C'<input()]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQ909Pz9FXUfdKTFFXTNa3VndJjOvoLREQzP2/38lkJwSAA)

Using `exit` requires extra brackets around  the whole expression so in this case `print` is 1 byte shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 33 bytes

```python
exit(['Bad','Good'][input()<'G'])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7Uis0QjWt0pMUVdR909Pz9FPTY6M6@gtERD00bdXT1W8/9/oBwA)

Prints to stderr, to save one byte over `print()`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 11 bytes

```
"GoodBad"qU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=Ikdvb2RCYWQicVU&input=Ikdvb2Qi)

#### Explanation:

```
"GoodBad"qU     U = Input             "Good"        "Bad"
"GoodBad"       String literal        "GoodBad"     "GoodBad"
         qU     Split at U            ["","Bad"]    ["Good",""]
-P              Join into a string    "Bad"         "Good"
```

### Alternative

```
"GoodBad"rU
```

`r` replaces `U` with `""`

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Ikdvb2RCYWQiclU&input=Ikdvb2Qi)

Answer (score 0):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 77 bytes

```
import'dart:io';main()=>print('BadGood'.replaceAll(stdin.readLineSync(),''));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxCoAwDEDR4yQF8QAWBV1c3DxBaDoE2qTULp6@1vE/PlNtvUsuVhvwiEUMfCZRdOtWqmhDOIhPM4a5xpIoxD0lfBqLDiC@ROP9akA3ATjne//nDw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pepe](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 104 bytes

```
rEEeREeEeeeEEErrEEreeEeeeEEEreeEEeEEEEreeEEeEEEEreeEEeeEeeREerREEreeEeeeeEereeEEeeeeEreeEEeeEeeREeReEree
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#S!an@EWeYmYmY0D@FW4XuY0DB*)

### With comments

```
# Prepare stacks
rEEe        # r ← Input
REeEeeeEEE  # R ← 'G'

# Create label i (outputs "Good")
rrEE { reeEeeeEEE reeEEeEEEE reeEEeEEEE reeEEeeEee } REe 

# Create label 'G' (outputs "Bad")
rREE { reeEeeeeEe reeEEeeeeE reeEEeeEee } REe 

# Compare values
ReE  # If the first letter of input is 'G', go to label 'G'
ree  # Otherwise, go to label i
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zozotez](http://zozotez.sylwester.no): 22

```
(?(=(r)'Bad)'Good'Bad)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [ScPL](https://scpl.dev), 61 bytes

```
ChooseFromMenu''[Good Bad]
Case
Text'Bad'
Case
Text'Good'
End
```

[Editor Link](https://editor.scpl.dev/?scpl=ChooseFromMenu%27%27%5BGood%20Bad%5D%0ACase%0AText%27Bad%27%0ACase%0AText%27Good%27%0AEnd)

The first argument to ChooseFromMenu is the title, which doesn't matter so we put an empty string. The second argument is the list of choices.

Cases do not require a label, they go based on order.

Seperators between things are only required when they are not seperated some other way, for example `a b` needs a space because `ab` is one argument, but `a'b'` does not because the ' starts another argument.

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>51</s> 42 bytes

```java
g->{if(g=="Bad")return"Good";return"Bad";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7LjsIwDDyTr7AiIbVSyQcQyoHD7okTR3YPoW2qlJJEsYOEUL@9pA8hH8b2eDzTqafaOd/Yrr6PPt56U0HVK0Q4K2PhzQDWLZKiBE9nangkLrtQMLa9/oMKLebzKUCX/olIphc62oqMs@JnbQ6LoIAFj6ChHNvd8W101pYlP6ma56GhGCz/da7mch0mQg6jZF9HapAQyuS5mdki4Sxhg2TaBVjDAcJ@OZ7ybS4vpOYhXCThE00641uEP8sL0EJ5378yzHPJhqnGDw)

Checks if input is `Bad`.

<sub>-9 to @JoKing</sub>

Comment: I mean, just comparing `g` to "Bad" saves 4 bytes. You can also remove the `else ` for 5 more, or even use a ternary operator for [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##PU5BboMwEDzHrxhZqgQS8QNCSaQeklNOOaY5OICRKdgWu0SKqrydOoCqPczuzuzstPqhtz7Urq1@pjDeO1ui7DQRzto6/Apg3RJrjvDwtkIfueTCg3XN9QY9NJTOUqCNfmpk2ykzupKtd@q4Np/LQYYF9zAopma7b4pCfulKHuTJ@0ru5mHKxb8/18SEIn7YzFwWcZaKVy6MH7BGAWG3iN9pNpcncd0rP7IKkWaTyA/Ct5MZjNIhdM@E0jQXr3dNfw)

Comment: @JoKing I actually tried to do a ternary `g.length()>3?`, but it was throwing an error for invalid operator. Thanks for help either way.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 31 bytes

```php
readline()=="Bad"?"Good":"Bad";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoJBWmpdckpmfp5CmoalQrVCUWlJalPe/KDUxJSczL1VD09ZWySkxRcleyT0/P0XJCsyx/l@rkJqckQ/SY/0fKAIA)

### Another way, 41 bytes

```php
["Bad"=>"Good","Good"=>"Bad"][readline()];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoJBWmpdckpmfp5CmoalQrVCUWlJalPc/WskpMUXJ1k7JPT8/RUkHQgG5INHY6KLUxJSczLxUDc1Y6/@1CqnJGfkg7db/gdIA)

Comment: Shorter: `['bad'=>'good'][readline()]??'bad';`

Answer (score 0):

### [GNU Smalltalk](http://smalltalk.gnu.org/), 34B

Please forgive me for submitting a code snippet if Smalltalk does have input. I am a complete novice to Smalltalk.

```
i<'C'ifTrue:['Good']ifFalse:['Bad']
```

You replace the name i with the intended input.

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, 38 bytes

```
Input Str1:"GoodBad 
sub(Ans,abs(inString(Ans,Str1)-5)+1,4
```

Prompts the user to input the string, then prints the other string as specified in the challenge.

**Explanation:**

```
Input Str1                               ;get the input
"GoodBad "                               ;leave "GoodBad " in Ans. closing quote
                                         ;  is added for clarity (isn't in program)
            inString(Ans,Str1)           ;get the 1-indexed position of the input
                                         ;  in "GoodBad "
        abs(                  -5)+1      ;subtract 5, get the absolute value,
                                         ;  then add 1
sub(Ans, ...                       ,4    ;get the substring of "GoodBad " starting
                                         ;  at the position just calculated with
                                         ;  a length of 4.  leave the result in Ans
                                         ;implicit print of Ans
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
’⁽ȯBad’$o
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWGx41zHzUuPfEeqfEFCBTJX9JcVJyMVRywRL3_PwUCBsA)

##### Explanation

```python
’⁽ȯBad’$o  # Implicit input
’⁽ȯBad’    # Compressed string "GoodBad"
       $o  # Remove the input
           # Implicit output
```